# I get a Error, but on other models it is working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I work with about the same ViewModels as other models.
But on this one I get some error almost al of them are 'self' errors.
I can't find where it come from.

See here te errors:
[image]

And this I my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine

class RouteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // MARK: Filtered Array
    @Published var myRoutes: [Route]?
    // MARK: Raw All Notes
    @Published var allRoutes: [Route]?
    
    // MARK: Search Text
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    // Combine Search
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    // MARK: New Note
    @Published var showAddRoutePopup: Bool = false
    @Published var boxNumberIdentificatie: [String]
    @Published var dateBringDate: Date
    @Published var customerIdentificatie: String = ""
    @Published var locationPlaceLogLat: GeoPoint
    
    // MARK: Alert
    @Published var showAlert: Bool = false
    @Published var alertMsg: String = ""
    
    // MARK: Edit Note
    @Published var editRoute: Route?
    
    // MARK: Log Status
    @AppStorage("log_status") var log_status: Bool = false
    // MARK: Logout Alert
    @Published var showLogoutPopup: Bool = false
    
    init(){
        fetchRoutes()
        
        // Combine Search
        cancellable = $searchText.removeDuplicates()
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { string in
                if string != ""{
                    self.filterRoutes(searchText: string)
                }
                else{
                    withAnimation{
                        self.myRoutes = self.allRoutes
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    
    // MARK: Fetching Notes
    func fetchRoutes(){
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
            log_status = false
            return
        }
        
        let routesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Routes")
        
        routesRef.order(by: "lastModified", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, err in
            guard let docs = snapshot?.documentChanges else{
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[self] in
                
                if allRoutes == nil{allRoutes = []}
                docs.forEach { doc in
                    if let route = try? doc.document.data(as: Route.self){
                     
                        switch doc.type{
                        case .added: allRoutes?.append(route)
                        case .modified: updateRoute(route: route)
                        case .removed: removeRoute(route: route)
                        }
                    }
                }
                sortRoutes()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sortRoutes(){
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let sorted = self.allRoutes?.sorted(by: { first, second in
                return second.dateAdd < first.dateAdd
            })
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[self] in
                allRoutes = sorted
                withAnimation(myRoutes == nil ? .none : .default){
                    myRoutes = allRoutes
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func filterRoutes(searchText: String){
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let filtered = self.allRoutes?.filter({ route in
                
                return route.customerId.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                
            })
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation{
                    self.myRoutes = filtered
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addRoute(){
        
        withAnimation{
            showAddRoutePopup = false
        }
        if customerIdentificatie == ""{return}
        
        let routesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Routes")
        
        if let editRoute = editRoute {
            
            routesRef.document(editRoute.id ?? "").updateData([
                "boxId": boxNumberIdentificatie,
                "dateBring": dateBringDate,
                "customerId": customerIdentificatie,
                "locationPlace": locationPlaceLogLat
            ])
            clearData()
            return
        }
        
        let route = Route(boxId: boxNumberIdentificatie, dateAdd: Date(), dateBring: dateBringDate, customerId: customerIdentificatie, locationPlace: locationPlaceLogLat)
        
        do{
            let _ = try routesRef.addDocument(from: route)
            clearData()
        }
        catch{
            clearData()
            alertMsg = error.localizedDescription
            showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func updateRoute(route: Route){
        if let index = myRoutes?.firstIndex(where: { currentRoute in
            return currentRoute.id == route.id
        }){
            allRoutes![index] = route
        }
    }
    
    func removeRoute(route: Route){
        if let index = myRoutes?.firstIndex(where: { currentRoute in
            return currentRoute.id == route.id
        }){
            allRoutes?.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteRoute(){
        guard let editRoute = editRoute else {
            return
        }
        
        let routesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Routes")
        
        routesRef.document(editRoute.id ?? "").delete()
        withAnimation{
            showAddRoutePopup = false
        }
        clearData()
    }
    
    func clearData(){
        boxNumberIdentificatie = [""]
        dateBringDate = Date()
        customerIdentificatie = ""
        editRoute = nil
    }
}
```

I hope somebody is seeing the problem what I didn't see.
Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages in text form and your attempts to resolve them

Comment: you have to init your vars like boxNumberIdentificatie, dateBringDate locationPlaceLogLat before do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your properties -- `dateBringDate` and `locationPlaceLogLat` -- do not have default values and are thus uninitialized by the time you call `fetchRoutes` in the `init` method. To fix, you should initialize them at the start of `init` or provide default values:

```
@Published var dateBringDate: Date = Date()
```

Basically, the problem is that Swift requires you to initialize an object's properties before calling any of that object's methods. That rule prevents errors that would occur if, for example, `fetchRoutes` tried to access the value of `dateBringDate`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think that this is the problem. 

I have tried the find the default of Firestone GeoPoint but I can't find it. Maybe you have the answer?
'

Comment: Interesting, I don't know anything about Firebase. Perhaps turning the property into an optional `GeoPoint` and letting it be `nil` by default would be best.